# Refresh Azure VM with a new Linux OS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, system-restore, azure

I created several VMs in Azure *classic* cloud service several years ago, and would like to retain them (size setting, DNS names, etc). But it looks impossible to me, as the old portal doesn't even exist any more and there seems [no way to reuse the old DNS names, i.e., the cloud service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34490112/). So here is my question,

What would Azure Linux VMs different from each other, apart from the obvious machine/host name, UUID etc?

If MS Azure doesn't support Refresh Azure VM to a new version officially, would the traditional *nix's tar save & restore do the trick? Or there are better tools nowadays?

PS. I don't like the Ubuntu's `apt upgrade` route because according to the docs that I read, it is not recommended and not guaranteed either, if I am to bring up my Ubuntu 15.04 to the latest.

Comment: Any 15.04 should have been updated a long time ago, before Trump got elected.

Comment: Not mine I'm afraid @GabrielaGarcia

Answer (score 1):

First, the Azure VM is just a logic group that consists of serial resources and it also a resource at the same time. The VM differ from others according to the resource ID which Azure set. So does all the Azure resources. In the same tenant, same subscription, the resource ID is unique which differs from others.

Then, you can convert the VM from Classic to ARM through convert the os disk to managed disk and then create a new VM with the managed disk. Follow the steps [Migrate the VM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/migrate-single-classic-to-resource-manager#migrate-the-vm).

Comment: I would like to retain those  Azure classic VMs (size setting, DNS names, etc) as  is, without converting them to ARM. But thanks for helpging though. upvoting.

Comment: So what you really want?

Comment: Have I not made myself clear enough? What part of my request you don't understand? I don't want to Migrate the VM, I want to keep them as-is as the _classic_ cloud service.